# How to make migrations from another project on a console application using .net6?

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework-6

I am trying to execute the command `add-migration` with a console application which I made a context in a project apart from the console application, but when I Try to run it, it gives me the error, I am using .NET 6:

```
Unable to resolve service for type 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Migrations.IMigrator'. This is often because no database provider has been configured for this DbContext. A provider can be configured by overriding the 'DbContext.OnConfiguring' method or by using 'AddDbContext' on the application service provider. If 'AddDbContext' is used, then also ensure that your DbContext type accepts a DbContextOptions<TContext> object in its constructor and passes it to the base constructor for DbContext.
```

Thats my context:

```
public class SchoolContext : DbContext
    {
        public DbSet<Student> Students { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Course> Courses { get; set; }
       
        public SchoolContext(DbContextOptions options) : base(options)
        {
        }

        
    }
```

That's my main

```
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using Persistencia;

var builder = new HostBuilder()
               .ConfigureServices((hostContext, services) =>
               {

                   services.AddLogging(configure => configure.AddConsole())
                   .AddDbContext<SchoolContext>(options =>
                   {
                       options.UseInMemoryDatabase( "testedb");
                   });
               }).UseConsoleLifetime();

var host = builder.Build();
```

Project Structure
[Project Structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7Tjot.png)

Comment: where do you need create migration folder, teste or presistencia  project ? have same way

Answer (score 0):

> The in-memory concept in meant to simulate your database in your memory (RAM). Migrations are used to generate/update your database schema to the connected database. The in-memory database doesn't need migrations. You can directly start your application and start using your DBContext without trying to add migrations.

### **But**

If you need to migrate with `SqlServer` , you can follow this tutorial.

1 - Install this package on console app

```
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer
```

2 - change your `AddDbContext` like *"Shop.Console" is console project name.
[more connection string options](https://www.connectionstrings.com/sql-server/).

```
services.AddDbContext<ShopDbContext>(options =>
{
      options
            .UseSqlServer("Server=[server];Database=[name]; User ID = [if have]; Password = [if have];Trusted_Connection=false;MultipleActiveResultSets=true",
             sqlServerOptionsAction: o => o.MigrationsAssembly("Shop.Console"));
});
```

3 - open `Package Manager Console` and run these commands

```
a- dotnet ef migrations add InitialContext  -p "Shop.Console" 
b- dotnet ef database update -p "Shop.Console"
```